# Usage of String.format in Java

Tags: java, string, format

What I wanted to print:

```
Coca-Cola      $ 11.00
Pepsi           $ 9.45
Sprite          $ 8.50
```

What end up printing:

```
Coca-Cola       $ 11
Pepsi       $ 9.45
Sprite       $ 8.5
```

My code:

```
public void test(){
    for (int i = 0; i<20; i++){
        System.out.print(product[i]);
        System.out.println(String.format("%20s%n", "$ "+price[i]));;

    }
```

I am looking for this for like 2 hours, perhaps I'm not that good specifying my search terms, but I'll try to avoid some more hours of searching and suffering by simply asking... Sorry for not knowing enough to properly find this on the forums or specify my title and thank you very much.

Comment: Search for "java string format right align".

Comment: Formatter: `%20s$%.2f"`, read more abt string [formatting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

Comment: Actually I can align the text to the right, but it aligns the whole line and I can't control the amount of space between the product and the price, the tricky part is aligning the product to the left and the price to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of your code is that it first prints the product **then** it try to print a formatted string.

The battle is already lost when it print those things separately. Because the second print needs to know the length of the product to determine how many spaces it needs to align the prices. That number is definitely not going to be the same.

Try this instead:

```
System.out.printf("%-20s$ %5.2f\n", product[i], price[i]);
```

Output:

```
Coca-Cola           $ 11.00
Pepsi               $  9.45
Sprite              $  8.50
```

The `%-20s` will left justify the product name, fill required number of spaces after the product name.

To align the decimal point, we need to specify the total length of the formatted number as well. With `%5.2`, we ask for a total length of 5, which `11.00` fits well, you can tune up this number if price is greater than 99.

Good luck.

Comment: The code is way better now, thanks. But is there a way to align all the prices to the right?

Comment: Keep getting >>Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '5'<< I am using Double for the price not Float (don't know if it makes any difference).

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for string.format 
public static String format(String format, Object... args)

Parameters

format-This is a format string.
args- This is the argument referenced by the format specifiers in the format string.If there are more arguments than format specifiers, the extra arguments are ignored. The number of arguments is variable and may be zero.